# In Wpf(Xaml), i have changed the format of date from(dd/mm/yyyy) to (yyyy-mm-dd). now i want to get the current date

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

In WPF(XAML), i have changed the format of date from(dd/mm/yyyy) to (yyyy-mm-dd) in date picker. now I want to get the current date when the windows form starts. 
I want to pick the current date when the form starts and shows the date in date picker using the XAML.
my code of changing the format:-

```
   <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding myVideModelProperty}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="335,31,0,0" 
      x:Name="DatePickerCustomerSupplied" Height="23" Width="171">
        <DatePicker.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
                                     Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd}}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.Resources>
    </DatePicker>
```

Comment: In your view-model, set `myVideModelProperty = DateTime.Now` on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by creating a full property in your view model and giving it a default value of DateTime.Now.

I.E.

```
    private DateTime _myVideModelProperty = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime MyVideModelProperty
    {
        get { return _myVideModelProperty; }
        set
        {
            _myVideModelProperty = value;
            // Don't forget to add your INotify here.
        }
    }
```